# Comma separate values with same key in a single index rather than different index in Php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to store values separated by comma where values are in a 2-Dimensional array.

```
for($i=1;$i<=$c;$i++) {
    marks_entered[$c]=$this->input->post('mark_'.$c);

    foreach( $another_mark_arr as $k => $v ) { 
        //k values are 2D1,2D2,2D3,2D4 ,,,2DN
        $mark_arr[$k] = $k.':'.$marks_entered[$c][$k].',';
        $newArr[] = $mark_arr[$k];
    }
}
print_r($newArr);
```

**Above code outputs:**

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 2D1:3, [1] => 2D2:6, [2] => 2D3:3, [3] => 2D4:2,............
    [15] => 2D1:1, [16] => 2D2:7, [17] => 2D3:2, [18] => 2D4:1,
)
```

How to Comma separate values with same key in a single index rather than different index as given below?

**Desired output:**

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 2D1:3,1 [1] => 2D2:6,7 [2] => 2D3:3,2 [3] => 2D4:2,1 ......[n]
)
```

Comment: what is the contents of `$another_mark_arr`. And what is `$c`. The first for loop in the question makes no sense

Comment: Where would you get the value after the comma from?

Comment: $another_mark_arr=Array ( [2D1] => 2D1:2, [2D2] => 2D2:2, .....) and $c is no of subjects. it varies for different exam and the for loop is edited now

Comment: value after comma is in index number 15,16,17....respectvely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restructure your foreach like this:

```
foreach( $another_mark_arr as $k => $v ) { 
    if(array_key_exists($k, $newArr)) {   // Check if key exists
        $newArr[$k] .= ','.$marks_entered[$c][$k];  // if exists, append using comma
    } else {
        $newArr[$k] = $k.':'.$marks_entered[$c][$k];  // Otherwise, add a new key with value
    }
}
```

Your resultant array will have keys with `2D1, 2D2,...` If you want to reset the keys to `0,1,...` then use [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values):

```
$newArr = array_values($newArr);
```